# ActiveAdmin giving timeout error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

When I try to access ActiveAdmin in local in my rails app, it loads way to slowly, and when pushing to heroku and trying to access my admin panel, it will give Application Error.

In my logs, I have:

```
2014-07-09T11:27:13.175216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/admin/login" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=30b8a647-6c82-4af5-b9a1-2d0eb3ecfa67 fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=0 service=30003 status=503 bytes=1644
2014-07-09T11:55:12.294230+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/admin/login" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=9b5c462a-6d8e-4f67-b19f-307d732ab4ca fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=30002 status=503 bytes=1644
```

What can it be? I can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it's a problem with to big association filters.

Disable the auto created filters and reenable them one by one, to find the problem filter.

This will help you if your filter is not to big:

```
filter :foo, as: :select, collection: Foo.pluck(:name, :id)
```

(but works only for rails > 4.0, you can build a similar thing by hand in rails 3.x)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is usualy because of auto created filters, you can disable filters by:

```
remove_filter :some_param
```

Also you can eager-load some association with *include* in scoped collection, and if you have a huge count of records may be it can help to set:

```
index pagination_total: false
```